# Почему less.js не компилирует файл?

Tags: less

Скачал less.js, подключил к странице:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.less" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/less.min.js" ></script>
```

Залил файлы на локальный хост OpenServer.
В styles.less вставил пример с сайта, но препроцессор ничего не компилирует.

В консоли вывелось следующее:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2384

Comment: На сервере компилировать надо...

Comment: Я добавил перед подключением скрипта код:

<script>
  less = {
    env: "development",
    async: true,
  };
</script>

Теперь в консоли:
rendered http://local.html-template/css/styles.less successfully.
less.min.js:13 css for http://local.html-template/css/styles.less generated in 89ms
less.min.js:13 less has finished. css generated in 90ms

Но я по прежнему не вижу скомпилированных стилей. Не думал, что всё будет так сложно.

Comment: Мне не понятны ваши ответы, объясните подробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/` это warning, а не error. Предупреждение о том, что данный способ устарел не останавливает выполнение программы.
Скомпилированных стилей вам видеть и не нужно, смотреть нужно на результаты их выполнения

Comment: Как же не нужно? Я хочу через LiveStyle + Sublime с помощью .map файлов править их прямо из браузера. Это что, не реально?

Comment: В этом случае лучше компилировать вне браузера